# Where to create parent model instances in feature test (Capybara)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am testing the creation of a product with Capybara, i.e., I am filling a form with automated test. This product belongs to certain models, for example, to a home.

I have two factory files to create this two models, the product and the house. In the form, user should select the home from a select (Drop down). I manage to do it, but the solution feels not clean:

(I am creating the home instance in the feature test, since I need a home to be selected in the form for the product. This house belongs to other models)

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'pry'

RSpec.describe 'Add a product features' do

  context "Create new product from add a product menu" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }
    let!(:home) { create(:home, name: "My Place", user: user) }

    before(:each) do
      # home.name = "My place"
      # home.save
    end

    before(:each) do
      # binding.pry
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
      visit menu_add_product_path

      click_link("Take a picture")

      expect(current_path).to eql('/products/new')
      binding.pry
      within('form') do
        attach_file('product_taken_photos_attributes_0_taken_pic', File.absolute_path('./app/assets/images/macbook1.jpg'))
        fill_in 'Brand', with: "Apple"
        fill_in 'Product type', with: "Smartphone"
        fill_in 'Price of purchase', with: 800.3
        fill_in 'Date of purchase', with: "2017-05-03"
        select("My place", :from => 'product_home_id')
      end
    end

    it 'should be successful' do
      binding.pry
      within('form') do
        fill_in 'Model', with: "Iphone 6"
      end

      click_button('Create Product')
      binding.pry

      expect(current_path).to eql(product_path(Product.last))
      expect(page).to have_content 'Iphone 6'
    end

    # it 'should not be successful' do
    #   click_button('Create Product')

    #   expect(current_path).to eql('/products') # the post products actually!
    #   expect(page).to have_content(/Model can\'t be blank/)
    # end
  end
end
```

Factories:

home.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :home do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "My Home#{n}" }
    address 'c/ Viladomat n200 50 1a'
    insurer
    house_type
    user
  end
end
```

product.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    model 'macbook pro'
    form_brand 'apple'
    form_product_type 'laptop'
    price_of_purchase 1200
    date_of_purchase Date.new(2017,06,06)
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "myemail#{n}@mail.com" }
    password 123456
  end
end
```

house_type.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :house_type do
    name 'Flat'
  end
end
```

If I use the let! operator to create a home for all the tests, the test fails:

```
let!(:home) { create(:home, name: "My Place", user: user) }
```

Console log:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible option "My place" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="select" path="/html/body/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/select">
```

But, if I create the home manually, before each test, it works

```
let(:home) { create(:home, name: "My Place", user: user) }

before(:each) do
  home.name = "My place"
  home.save
end
```

Why is the let! not working? If I put a binding.pry in my test, in both cases I have the created home in my database.

Comment: Required relationships should be defined in the factory so you don’t have to manually set the up  every time you need to create a home. You also shouldn’t really be mixing `let` and `before` like that, but rather passing parameters to the factory creation methods. Add your `home` factory definition to your question for a more specific answer

Comment: I added the factories

Comment: Updated my answer to include the missing `address` field in the home factory -- other than that it should be about right.

Answer (score 1):

You should be configuring your factories to automatically create needed default associations so you can create a needed instance in your tests without having to create all the other non-specialized records. Your home factory should look something like

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :home do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Home#{n}" }
    address { 'c/ Viladomat n200 50 1a' } # You might want to define this to use a sequence too so it's unique when you create multiples
    insurer
    house_type
    user
  end
end
```

Something like that would then let you create a valid `Home` instance by just calling `create(:home)`.  If you want to customize any of associations/parameters you can pass them to the factory create/build method.  So in your example it would just become

```
let(:home) { create(:home, name: 'My place') }
```

If you wanted to also manually create the `user` object, so you can call `login(user...)` rather than having to access an auto generated user like   `login(home.user...)` then you would do

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let!(:home) { create(:home, name: 'My place', user: user }
```

Note the use of `let!` for `home` rather than `let`. This is because `let` is lazily evaluated so the instance won't actually be built until you first call `home` in your test - Since, when calling `login_as(user...`, you don't call `home` in your test you need to use `let!` instead so the object is created before your test is run. You also probably want to be using FactoryBot sequences in things like the `email` of your user factory, so that you can create more than one user in tests.

Additionally you're calling `expect(current_path).to eql('/new_from_camera')`, which will lead to flaky tests since the `eql` matcher doesn't have waiting behavior built-in. Instead you should always prefer the Capybara provided matchers which would mean calling `expect(page).to have_current_path('/new_form_camera')` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. With the let! strategy it does not work (I updated my question for clarification). With before(:each) it works. Is the before-each strategy so wrong? Why the let! strategy does not work?

Comment: @AlbertMunichMar There's no point in using both `before` and `let!` - if you wanted to use `before` you could just create the `home` instance in the before block and not use `let` at all.  Looking at the page should tell you immediately why your test is failing - You're creating the home with a name of "My Place" but then trying to select "My place" (different case on the "p")

Comment: @AlbertMunichMar Also while you keep adding more to the question -- the line `expect(current_path).to eql(product_path(Product.last))` is going to end up being really flaky for you because there's no guarantee that when `click_button` returns  the new product has been created  - You need an assertion on a visible change on the page that indicates the product has been created - like `expect(page).to have_text('Product created')` (whatever message you show to the user once creation has succeeded) before using `Product.last` - and again you should use `have_current_path` (don't use `eql`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand that I should assert the notice message "Product was added". But I am achieving the same while testing if the name of the created product is in the new page right?

Comment: How do I change then if the current path is /products/3 (products/:id). In order to create the path, I need to pass the id, and the id is the one from the last product. If I am in the show page, that means the product was created, I don't understand why /products/#{Product.last.id} should not work

Comment: @AlbertMunichMar `click_button` can return before the product has been created (on any driver other than rack_test) so to make sure the test waits until `Product.last` is valid you just need to use one of Capybaras expectations (for visible content that indicates the Product has been created) after the `click_button` and before you use `Product.last` - The waiting behavior of Capybaras expectations will then ensure `Product.last` is usable.  However, you really should think about whether testing the URL makes any sense in these tests since users generally don't care what the exact URL is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the associations directly in the `home` factory:

```
let(:insurer) { create(:insurer) }
let(:house_type) { create(:house_type) }
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:home) { create(:home, name: "My place", insurer: insurer, house_type: house_type, user: user) }
```